# sort by name on bash same as graphical on windows

Tags: windows, bash, sorting

I have this folder in windows

[image: text]

if I do a simple ls , find, either in bash (cygwin) or msdos, it shows me like this.

```
$ ls -1
su-01-01.jpg
su-01-02-03.jpg
su-01-12-13.jpg
su-01-14.jpg
su-01-15.jpg
su-01-16.jpg
su-01-18.jpg
su-01-19.jpg
su-01-20.jpg
su-01-21.jpg
su-01-31.jpg
su-01-34.jpg
su-01-35.jpg
su-01-38.jpg
su-01-39.jpg
su-01-42-43.jpg
su-01-44.jpg
su-01-45.jpg
su-01-47.jpg
su-01-48.jpg
su01-00.jpg
su01-04.jpg
su01-05.jpg
su01-06.jpg
su01-07.jpg
su01-08.jpg
```

I have tried ordering and it does not take into account 0 00 1

```
$ ls -1 |sort -V
su01-00.jpg
su01-04.jpg
su01-05.jpg
su01-06.jpg
su01-07.jpg
su01-08.jpg
su01-09.jpg
su01-10.jpg
su01-11.jpg
su01-22-23.jpg
su01-24.jpg
su01-25.jpg
su01-26.jpg
su01-27.jpg
su01-28-29.jpg
su01-30.jpg
su01-32.jpg
su01-33.jpg
su01-40-41.jpg
su-01-01.jpg
su-01-02-03.jpg
su-01-12-13.jpg
su-01-14.jpg
su-01-15.jpg
```

but how do I make it ignore the (-)?

thank you very much for your help

Comment: [Windows cmd is **not** MSDOS](https://superuser.com/a/1411173/241386), don't call it like that. And why does it have to be bash? It'll be much easier to be done in PowerShell because you can call the exact sorting function like what explorer does

Answer (score 1):

`find` doesn't guaranty alphabetical ordering; `ls` and `sort` do, but the char `-` value is `45` while the `0` char value is `48`, so `su-` will come ahead of the `su0` in an alphabetical sorting.

While a `printf '%s\n' su* | LANG=en_US.utf8 sort -n` seems to display the files the way you want, the best thing to do for making your life easier would be to rename some of the files:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for f in su0*
do
    mv "$f" "su-0${f#su0}"
done
```

---

###### Update

renaming the files to `001.jpg` `002.jpg` ...

```bash
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob

n=1
while IFS='' read -r file
do
    printf -v newname '%03d.%s' "$((n++))" "${file##*.}"
    printf '%q %q %q\n' mv "$file" "$newname"
done < <(
    printf '%s\n' su* |
    sed -nE 's,su-?([^/]*)$,\1/&,p' |
    LANG=C sort -nt '-' |
    sed 's,[^/]*/,,'
)
```

Comment: Yes
My goal is to rename the whole folder to 001 002 003. 

But it is necessary before the terminal detects them in the same order as shown on the graphical screen.

```$ printf '%s\n' su* | sort -n
su-01-01.jpg
su-01-02-03.jpg
su-01-12-13.jpg
su-01-14.jpg
su-01-15.jpg
su-01-16.jpg
su-01-18.jpg
su-01-19.jpg
su-01-20.jpg
su-01-21.jpg
su-01-31.jpg
su-01-34.jpg
su-01-35.jpg
su-01-38.jpg
su-01-39.jpg
su-01-42-43.jpg
su-01-44.jpg
su-01-45.jpg
su-01-47.jpg
su-01-48.jpg
su01-00.jpg
su01-04.jpg
su01-05.jpg
su01-06.jpg
su01-07.jpg
```

Comment: I don't know how to put code in an answer, sorry.

I don't understand how windows sees it like this (well) and how to replicate it in the terminal.

Comment: try `printf '%s\n' su* | LANG=en_US.utf8 sort -n`

Comment: take a look at my update

Comment: Thank you very much Fravadona.    

I didn't know that trick and it leaves it as it is in windows. Now I can rename well and in order, :)      

Thanks also for the script update.

Comment: @joanis you're right, exporting the correct locale would be easier: `export LANG=en_US.utf8; n=0; for file in su*; do n=$((n+1)); mv "$file" "$(printf  '%03d.%s' "$n" "${file##*.}")"; done` the problem is that only `C` and `POSIX` locales are guaranteed to exist

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to control the sort order in Bash, both for `ls` and `sort`, so to set your `LANG` variable to the locale you want.

In your .bashrc or .profile, add

```
export LANG=en_US.utf8
```

and then

```
ls -1
```

or

```
ls -1 | sort
```

will output the order you're looking for.

If you want to test with different locales and see their effect, your can set LANG one command at a time. For example, compare the output of these commands:

```
LANG=en_US.utf8 ls -1  # what you're looking for
LANG=C ls -1           # "ASCIIbetic" order
LANG=fr_FR.utf8 ls -1  # would consider é as between e and f
```